# Installing ROS2 python version

Tags: ros, ros2, rosdep, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to install ROS2 Crystal on the machine which already has ROS Melodic. I follow the standard guide https://docs.ros.org/en/crystal/Installation/Linux-Install-Binary.html
At the step 'Installing the missing dependencies', when I try to run **rosdep install** it gives the following warning

WARNING: ROS_PYTHON_VERSION is unset. Defaulting to 2

I've tried to set it manually  with ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3 but the warning persists. Will this break installation in some way? How do I set it to python3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390678/installing-ros2-python-version/) by [dmonkoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/89384/dmonkoff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**export ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3** solved the issue

---

Originally posted by [dmonkoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/89384/dmonkoff/) with karma: 16 on 2021-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0